# return url.action as json object mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

My Controller method returns Json object which has url formed as shown below :

```
return Json(new { url = Url.Action("ShowContact", "Customer", new { vm = contactVM }) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In the ajax call's success code, I want to assign this url to window.location.href so I can redirect to view as per url formed. But return value of ajax call shows plain text value for route value passed as part of url.

[image: snapshot from inspect element]

Hence, I'm not getting whatever route value I want to pass to the redirect action method of my controller.

So what are the options I have in order to pass my route value which is complex c# object including collections? Is there any better approach to achieve what I want to do?

Thanks,

Comment: What gets assigned to contactVM? Not sure what you mean by route value

Comment: contactVM is viewmodel object which I want to pass to my action method

Comment: What on earth is the point of making an ajax call if you then immediately redirect. Just do a normal submit.

Comment: And since `contactVM` is clearly a complex object, even if you used the correct syntax, this probably wont work anyway. You should not pass complex objects to a GET method. Apart from the ugly query string, if the model contains properties which are complex objects or collections, binding will fail and there is a chance you could exceed the query string limit and throw an exception

Comment: @StephenMuecke

I totally agree with concerns in your comments. I know what I was trying to do is not good but I needed to be back on client side after server side call hence I thought of such implementation.

Now I dropped my idea of such implementation and taking alternate way.

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try piecing it together:

```
return Json(
    new
    {
        url = Url.Action("ShowContact", "Customer"),
        vm = contactVM
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then on the client:

```
var url = result.url + '?vm=' + JSON.stringify(result.vm);
```

Granted, I've never tested this.

Comment: above solution works but results in very lengthy n nasty url... 

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the url string directly instead of 'Url.Action()'.
Something like this:

```
string url = "Customer/ShowContact?vm=" + contactVM;

return Json(url , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: it doesn't work as suggested by you. It just adds up fully qualified name of my object type to url i.e.

**Customer/ShowContact?vm=<NameSpace>.ContactVM**

Answer (score 0):

Simple and short

return Json(new { redirectUrl = @Url.Action("View", "Controller") });