# MVC action controller not rendering the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

after a compiling a form needed for register on the website( Registration.cshtml ), the form data are sent in a sqlite db ( successfully). Returning from that, i want to be sent to a Main.cshtml webpage. The problem is that the Action controller that is suposed to render the Main.cshtml view, isn't doing it.

I've tryed changing the Redirect/RedirectToAction and View methods many times, but it was a failure.

```
   return View("Main");
   return RedirectToAction("Main");
   return JavaScript("window.location = window.location.origin + /Pages/Main");
```

**PagesController.cs**

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Register {
        if (insert data in db == true) {
            return RedirectToAction("Main");
        }

        return View();
   }

   public ActionResult Main(){
        return View();
   }
```

**Main.cshtml**

```
    @{
         Layout = "~/Views/Layouts/LoggedMasterPage.cshtml";
         ViewBag.Title = "Benvenuto in ETL365"; 
     }
     @section Head{
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Main.css" />
          <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Main.js"></script>
     }
```

**Part of my Register.js**

```
         $("#register").dxButton({
             text: "Registrati",
             type: "normal",
             hint: "Clicca per registrarti",
             onClick: function () {
               if($('#password').
               dxValidator('instance').validate().isValid &&
               $('#email').dxValidator('instance').validate().isValid) {
                     let email = $("#email").dxTextBox('instance').option('value');
                     let pass = $("#password").dxTextBox('instance').option('value');

                     $.ajax({
                         url: window.location.origin + '/Pages/Register',
                         type: "POST",
                         data: '{"email":"' + email + '","password":"' + pass + '"}',
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         dataType: "json",
                      });
               }
             }
          });
```

I've already used breakpoints on Main.cshtml, and it actually gets in there after the

```
     return View();
```

done by the action Main().
What i expect is to be redirected to the mylocalhost:xxxx/Pages/Main
What i get is absolute nothing, I'm always in mylocalHost:xxxx/Pages/Register

Comment: because Javascript is handling the http request, the redirect is not passed to the page. You must process this in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `RedirectToAction` for AJAX call response because AJAX requests are intended to update the view without reloading whole page. You need to pass the URL as JSON response like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(string email, string password) 
{
    if (condition) // put your condition here
    {
        return Json(new { 
            status = "Success", 
            url = Url.Action("Main", "Pages")
        });
    }

    // since this controller receives AJAX request, the partial view should be used instead
    return PartialView("_Register");
}
```

Then in AJAX `success` condition you can check response status and redirect to target URL:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Register", "Pages")',
    type: "POST",
    data: { email: email, password: pass },
    success: function (result) {
        if (typeof result.status !== undefined && result.status == "Success") {
            location.href = result.url; // redirect to main page
        }
        else {
            $('#register').html(result); // refresh partial view
        }
    }
});
```

Related issue:

[return url.action as json object mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217361/return-url-action-as-json-object-mvc)

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect to your main page after a successfull ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
...
    success:
    {
    location.href = 'mylocalhost:xxxx/Pages/Main'
    }
...
```